# Strange phenomenon with substring and charindex

Tags: sql, sql-server

When comparing the code snippets below, you can see that the last element of the 'result 1' result set, only has one character (a comma) appending the number, whereas the other numbers (rows 1 - 3) have a comma and a number appending the 4 digits that I want.

In the 'Result 2' result set, I specifically change the length of the substring to be the string length minus **two characters**, yet the last element only removes a single element, the trailing comma, while the rows 1 - 3 remove both the number and the trailing comma. There is no blank space in the last row. Please could someone advise why this is happening?

Code 1:

```
select substring(c,2,charindex(',',c,2)) as empno
       from table t
   where len(c) > 1
       and substring(c,1,1) = ','
```

Result 1:

```
7654,7
7698,7
7782,7
7788,
```

Code 2:

```
select substring(c,2,charindex(',',c,2)-2) as empno
       from table t
   where len(c) > 1
       and substring(c,1,1) = ','
```

Result 2:

```
7654
7698
7782
7788
```

*edit: table t is:-

```
 c
    ----------------------
    ,7654,7698,7782,7788,
    7654,7698,7782,7788,
    654,7698,7782,7788,
    54,7698,7782,7788,
    4,7698,7782,7788,
    ,7698,7782,7788,
    7698,7782,7788,
    698,7782,7788,
    98,7782,7788,
    8,7782,7788,
    ,7782,7788,
    7782,7788,
    782,7788,
    82,7788,
    2,7788,
    ,7788,
    7788,
    788,
    88,
    8,
    ,
```

Comment: It might seem silly, but no, we can't "see". We don't have access to the tables `t1` or `t100`. Without sample data, it's much harder (or impossible) to advise.

Comment: This seems awfully convoluted to me.  It might be better if you tell us what you are trying to do.  I'll be there is an easier way.

Comment: I've updated the question to make this a bit simpler to answer, thanks for your tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CHARINDEX:**

```
Returns part of a character, binary, text, or image expression in SQL Server.
```

is defined as:

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

AND

**SUBSTRING:**

```
Returns part of a character, binary, text, or image expression in SQL Server.
```

is defined as:

```
SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
```

Query1:

```
substring(c,2,charindex(',',c,2))
```

In above charIndex returns first position of ',' i.e. `6` in every case.
So the returned value is acting as length for the substring which is `6` and that's why you are getting each record of `6 lengths`.

Query 2:

```
substring(c,2,charindex(',',c,2)-2)
```

In above charIndex returns first position of ',' i.e. `6` in every case. But also you are `reducing the length` by `subtracting 2` from it.
So the returned value is acting as length for the substring which is `4` now and that's why you are getting each record of `4 lengths` in this query.

See this query1 and query2 represent `CHARINDEX` returned values:

```
       c                query1  query2
,7654,7698,7782,7788,   6        4
,7698,7782,7788,        6        4
,7782,7788,             6        4
,7788,                  6        4
```

Comment: thank you, I'm still unsure why, when comparing result 1 and result 2 from my question above, when I subtract 2 chars from result 2, it does not cause the last row to become '778', i.e., it should remove '8,' but only removes the ','?

Comment: @SallyPeters it is because the last row also has the length of 6 characters and the `charindex` is returning `6` to the position of `,`. Now substring taking `2` as a `start` and using `6 - 2 i.e. 4` as a length. If you see position `2` in the last row i.e. `,7788,` is `first 7` and from `first 7` string of 4 characters length is `7788` and `,` is `6th` character in it. That's why it is showing 7788 in the last row.